# Roots of the polynomial $2x^5-3x^4$

Tags: calculus

To sketch the curve of a polynomial function, I have to solve for all of the possible roots of the polynomial. However, I’m not sure exactly how to do this. I thought you can simplify the polynomial as much as possible and then factorize. But when I do this, I end up not finding all of the solutions. The curve I am trying to sketch is $y= 2x^5 - 3x^4$ .  I am very confused by this and any help would be appreciated, thank you.  Apologies as for some reason it is not letting me upload an image of my attempt at this question.

Comment: You can indeed factor your polynomial. Just ask yourself, “What common factor do both terms of $y$ possess?”

Comment: Please don't upload a picture unless it's a graph, which provides an illustration to the problem.  Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter A picture is useful here, since the question is about graphing a polynomial and OP specifically wants help fixing their graph.

Comment: @B.Mehta Therefore I say *unless it's a graph*.  OP's "attempt" to the question in order to "solve for all the possible roots" can be both graphical and *algebraic*.  Given that the original version of the question is *not* rendered in MathJax (I [edit]ed this question to include MathJax, which is *required* for math objects.), I made my previous comment to explain why uploading pictures *as a shortcut to typing equations* is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most definitely factor your quintic:$$y=2x^5-3x^4=x^4(2x-3)$$Now set $y=0$ and find the corresponding values of $x$. Now, use the two rules

- if the degree of $x$ is one, the function passes through the $x$ axis
- if the degree of $x$ is even, the function touches the $x$ axis.
- if the degree of $x$ is three, the function “flattens” along the $x$ axis and goes through.

If you want a more accurate graph, then you’ll need to use the power of derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, they have been very helpful and thank you Frank W for the extra tips on sketching the curve. What i’m mainly confused by is when i simplified 2x^5 - 3x^4 = 0 to 2x-3 = 0, i only got x=3/2 as the solution, not x = 0.

Comment: @user564900 When $y=0$, then $x^4(2x-3)=0$ so either $x^4=0$ or $2x-3=0$

Comment: But why don’t i get x=0 as a solution when i divide both sides of ‘2x^5 - 3x^4’ by x^4  to get 2x - 3 and then solve for x? What am i missing?

Comment: You see when you divide through by x^m for any m, it is automatically assumed x cannot take the value 0. To be honest, you would be better off considering a theorem from the axioms of Mathematics, however let me give you a simple example. There is a HUGE difference between the equation (1) $x=y$ and (2) $1=x/y$ and (3) $1=y/x$. (1) says x,y is Real. (2) says x is Real but y is not 0. (3) says y is Real but x is not 0. It is important that we understand the **provided form** of the equation from (i.e. the way it is given) as this decides it's functional limits. Let me state some axioms next...

Comment: I'm not sure how much mathematics you have studied but this seems high school level. If we push into Tertiary education we get the standard axioms of Mathematics although I'm not 100% sure i gave a link at the end... Axioms of the Real numbers will show what we can and can't do **by definition** of the Real numbers.  Take for example the axiom that says $a=a \frac bb$. This does **NOT** imply equivalence to $ab=ab$ as this statement is invalid under our previous equation. Someone correct me if I am wrong. But this is my understanding. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is what i was looking for. So to check my understanding, should you never divide both sides of an equation by x^m (where m is any real number) when solving for all possible solutions of that equation, since performing this division assumes x is not equal to 0 thereby eliminating that solution? Instead, i should attempt to solve the equation by other methods such as factorising by grouping? I was confused because my teacher divided both sides by x before solving. When exactly is it okay to do this? Here are the steps he performed:

Comment: x^5 -5x^3 + 10x = 0.        —> x^4 -5x^2 + 10 = 0.   —> (x^2 -5/2)^2 -25/4 + 10 = 0. He then concluded that this equation has no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

$y=2x^5-3x^4=x^4(2x-3)\Rightarrow x=\frac 32 , 0$.

Shouldn't be too hard to find the first and second derivatives for turning points and inflection then sketch.

Here is the answer...

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D+2x%5E5+-+3x%5E4